# ThreadLocal versus Member Variable in a Thread in Java

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, thread-local

Can we get back reference to a member variable of a Thread like the way we get for ThreadLocal?

For example, lets say we use a counter variable to counter amount of requests processed by the Thread in a ThreadLocal variable. Consider that we are using a ThreadPool Executer for reusing threads. Now every Thread keeps a reference to a ThreadLocal counter variable and it can increment its own copy after every request. 
In a similar manner if i have a Member variable inside a Runnable, can i get back a reference to it? The Thread is anyway being reused.

Answer (score 1):

> if i have a Member variable inside a Runnable, can i get back a reference to it?

When you say "a Runnable", you're talking about some object that implements the `Runnable` interface.  There is nothing magic about `Runnable` and there is nothing magic about a `run()` method.

The member variables of your `Runnable` object are just like the member variables of any other object, and your code accesses them in the same way.

---

P.S., Usually, when you see `ThreadLocal` in a program, it means

- The program used to be single-threaded,
- It keeps a lot of its state in `static` variables,
- Somebody added multi-threading as an after-thought, and
- It makes sense for some of that static state to be duplicated for each thread.

I would almost never use `ThreadLocal` in a new program, because I try hard not to write any code that depends on static variables, and if you're using `ThreadLocal` for non-static data, you're probably making your program way more complicated than it needs to be.